# How to use invalid variable names in exec or eval?

Tags: python, exec, eval

I want to calculate a formula with variables in dictionary. For example:

```
d = {'a': 1}
exec('b=a+1', globals(), d) # d => { 'a': 1, 'b': 2 }
```

Since the data source of the dictionary is from outside of Python (e.g., Json / Yaml ), The key name of the dictionary can be invalid as variable name of Python. So the following code:

```
d = {':a': 1}
exec('b=:a+1', globals(), d) # expected d => { ':a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

throws error:

```
File "<string>", line 1
b=:a
  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Do you have any idea to use the invalid variable in exec or eval?

Comment: Use regex and strip off invalid chars and leading digits.

Comment: `exec` and `eval` require the input to be valid Python. Why are you getting something like `:a+1` in the first place? What if the input is `this is an invalid expression + 3`, what do you plan on doing with that?

Comment: You have a logic problem.  You cannot parse and calculate completely arbitrary input data.  There must be *some* variable naming rules, and you have to know what they are.  If a variable name is valid under those rules but invalid in Python you must convert it before calling exec/eval.  The algorithm you use for name conversion must avoid generating a new name that happens to match another name already in use.

Comment: If you aren't controlling the input source, be aware that `exec` is very dangerous.

Comment: You would have to map each key in `d` to a valid Python variable name such as `_0`, `_1`, etc. Then use those names in the code that's executed. You haven't said where that code comes from, so it may not be feasible.

Comment: `exec` itself isn't dangerous although the code given to it may be depending on its source.

Comment: [questioner] Hi thanks for many comments. (1) I would not like to throw exception in this case. (2) I understood security concern is here. But in the mean time let me assume there are only good people here. Escaping SQL/Command injection is another big problem. (3), replacing variable name is promising for me . Let me post solution later.

Answer (score 0):

[Replace based approach]

How about this? I confirmed this works correctly.

But this can not handle new invalid variable allocation like ":b = :a + 1".

```
d = {':a': 1}
expression = 'b=:a+1'

def exec2(expression, d):

    d2 = {}
    keymap={}
    for idx, (k, v) in enumerate(d.items()):
        k2 = "_" + str(idx)
        d2[k2] = v
        keymap[k2] = k

        expression = expression.replace(k, k2)

    # d2 => {'_0': 1}
    # expression => b=_0+1

    exec(expression, globals(), d2)

    for k2, v in d2.items():
        if k2 in keymap:
            k = keymap[k2]
            d[k] = v
        else:
            d[k2] = v
    # d => {':a': 1, 'b': 2}
    return d
```

Answer (score 0):

[Naive approach using d[k] in expression ]

If we can enforce to use 'd[k]' in expression to its author, then we can handle this without replacement.

This approach can also handle new invalid variable allocation like ":b = :a + 1".

But in this approach, authors must be aware of this escaping format...

```
def exec3(expression, d):
    exec(expression, globals(), d)
    return d

d = {':a': 1}
expression = 'b= d[":a"] + 1'
exec3(expression, d) # d => {':a': 1, 'b': 2}

d = {':a': 1}
expression = 'd[":b"] = d[":a"] + 1'
exec3(expression, d) # d => {':a': 1, ':b': 2}
```